# kernelspec is not installed and Jupyter-notebook not found, though pip says it is

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a python script from vs code. A month ago, the environment was working perfectly, but today nope won't run. go figure. 
Any and all attempts to install or update packages, e.g. `python.exe -m pip install -U jupyter --user`, returns "Requirement already satisfied".
Checking jupyter version says its not found.

```
python -m jupyter notebook --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dayneo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 192, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\dayneo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter.py", line 10, in <module>
    run_module('jupyter_core')
  File "C:\Users\dayneo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 208, in run_module
    return _run_code(code, {}, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\dayneo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\dayneo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_core\__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\dayneo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 247, in main
    command = _jupyter_abspath(subcommand)
  File "C:\Users\dayneo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 133, in _jupyter_abspath
    raise Exception(
Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found.
```

Trying to install it, says its already there.

```
pip install -U jupyter       
Requirement already up-to-date: jupyter in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: nbconvert in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jupyter) (5.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: qtconsole in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jupyter) (4.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: ipywidgets in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jupyter) (7.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: jupyter-console in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jupyter) (6.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: ipykernel in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jupyter) (5.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: notebook in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jupyter) (6.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: entrypoints>=0.2.2 in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (0.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: testpath in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: jinja2>=2.4 in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (2.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: traitlets>=4.2 in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (4.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: jupyter-core in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (4.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: bleach in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: defusedxml in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: mistune<2,>=0.8.1 in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (0.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pandocfilters>=1.4.1 in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: nbformat>=4.4 in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (5.0.4)      
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pygments in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (2.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: jupyter-client>=4.1 in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from qtconsole->jupyter) (5.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: ipython-genutils in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from qtconsole->jupyter) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3" in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from ipywidgets->jupyter) (7.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0 in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from ipywidgets->jupyter) 
(3.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jupyter-console->jupyter) (3.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: tornado>=4.2 in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from ipykernel->jupyter) (6.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: Send2Trash in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: prometheus-client in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (0.7.1)   
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyzmq>=17 in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (18.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: terminado>=0.8.1 in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (0.8.3)    
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jinja2>=2.4->nbconvert->jupyter) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: decorator in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from traitlets>=4.2->nbconvert->jupyter) (4.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from traitlets>=4.2->nbconvert->jupyter) (1.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-core->nbconvert->jupyter) (227)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: webencodings in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from bleach->nbconvert->jupyter) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from nbformat>=4.4->nbconvert->jupyter) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jupyter-client>=4.1->qtconsole->jupyter) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pickleshare in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets->jupyter) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: backcall in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets->jupyter) (0.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: colorama; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets->jupyter) (0.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: jedi>=0.10 in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets->jupyter) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools>=18.5 in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; 
python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets->jupyter) (41.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: wcwidth in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0->jupyter-console->jupyter) (0.1.8)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pywinpty>=0.5; os_name == "nt" in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from terminado>=0.8.1->notebook->jupyter) (0.5.7)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyrsistent>=0.14.0 in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.4->nbconvert->jupyter) (0.15.6)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: attrs>=17.4.0 in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.4->nbconvert->jupyter) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: parso>=0.5.2 in c:\users\dayneo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jedi>=0.10->ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets->jupyter) (0.6.0)
```

How do you proceed from here?

Comment: Waste of time kind of issues to be dealing with. 
Uninstall EVERYTHING and reinstall from scratch. 
Followed this process https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial again. Hopefully nothing breaks again and I can get down to actually getting something done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of Python extension 2020 / 02 / 06 is the cause of the error. Try to uninstall the latest version and install another previous version. It should work.

Comment: The goto club to beat every problem with nowadays. Uninstall and start again. 
;)

Comment: Couldn't confirm if this exact version was the issue, but uninstall and reinstall of everything got it working again.
Real time waster.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Had to manually add path:

`C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\Scripts`

then I restarted my IDE to make sure Path has refreshed.